# Serverless API Gateway Resource not coming back after manual delete on aws.com

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, serverless-framework, aws-api-gateway

I was trying to delete a test `GET` resource I manually created on an AWS API Gateway but it deleted my `POST` that was in the same resource path and now when I `sls deploy` that lambda resource is not coming back on the API Gateway's list of resources:

```
functions:
  updateLibrary:
    environment:
      ...
    handler: updates/lambda.handler
    events:
      - http:
          path: library/updated
          method: post
          private: true
```

Missing the `library/updated` `POST` resource

[image: AWS API Gateway Resources, missing resource]

What an old deployment of the dev stage looks like with the `library/updated` `POST` resource:

[image]

What the `sls deploy` logs result in:

```shell
Serverless: Stack update finished...
Serverless: Invoke aws:info
Serverless: [AWS cloudformation 200 0.484s 0 retries] describeStacks({ StackName: '***********-********-***' })
Serverless: [AWS cloudformation 200 0.508s 0 retries] listStackResources({ StackName: '***********-********-***' })
Service Information
service: ***********-********
stage: dev
region: **-****-*
stack: ***********-********-***
resources: 26
api keys:
  None
endpoints:
  POST - https://**********.execute-api.**-****-*.amazonaws.com/dev/library/updated
  POST - https://**********.execute-api.**-****-*.amazonaws.com/dev/merge/approved
functions:
  updateLibrary: ***********-********-***-updateLibrary
  mergePR: ***********-********-***-mergePR
layers:
  None
Serverless: [AWS sts 200 0.452s 0 retries] getCallerIdentity({})
Serverless: [AWS apigateway 200 0.633s 0 retries] getRestApis({ position: undefined, limit: 500 })
Serverless: [AWS apigateway 200 0.404s 0 retries] getStage({ restApiId: '**********', stageName: 'dev' })
Serverless: [AWS apigateway 200 0.577s 0 retries] updateStage({ restApiId: '**********',
  stageName: 'dev',
  patchOperations: 
   [ { op: 'replace',
       path: '/accessLogSettings/destinationArn',
       value: 'arn:aws:logs:**-****-*:**************:log-group:/aws/api-gateway/***********-********-***' },
     { op: 'replace',
       path: '/accessLogSettings/format',
       value: '{"requestTime":"$context.requestTime","requestId":"$context.requestId","apiId":"$context.apiId","resourceId":"$context.resourceId","resourcePath":"$context.resourcePath","path":"$context.path","httpMethod":"$context.httpMethod","status":"$context.status","authLatency":"$context.authorizer.integrationLatency","integrationLatency":"$context.integrationLatency","integrationStatus":"$context.integrationStatus","responseLatency":"$context.responseLatency","responseLength":"$context.responseLength","errorMessage":"$context.error.message","format":"SLS_ACCESS_LOG","version":"1.0.0"}' },
     { op: 'replace', path: '/*/*/logging/dataTrace', value: 'true' },
     { op: 'replace', path: '/*/*/logging/loglevel', value: 'INFO' },
     [length]: 4 ] })
Serverless: Invoke aws:deploy:finalize
Serverless: [AWS s3 200 0.511s 0 retries] listObjectsV2({ Bucket: '***********-********-***-serverlessdeploymentbucket-**************',
  Prefix: 'serverless/***********-********/dev' })
Serverless: Removing old service artifacts from S3...
Serverless: [AWS s3 200 0.503s 0 retries] deleteObjects({ Bucket: '***********-********-***-serverlessdeploymentbucket-**************',
  Delete: 
   { Objects: 
      [ { Key: 'serverless/***********-********/dev/******************-2020-02-09T03:31:30.226Z/***********-********.zip' },
        { Key: 'serverless/***********-********/dev/******************-2020-02-09T03:31:30.226Z/compiled-cloudformation-template.json' },
        { Key: 'serverless/***********-********/dev/******************-2020-02-09T03:31:30.226Z/custom-resources.zip' },
        [length]: 3 ] } })
Serverless: Publishing service to the Serverless Dashboard...
Serverless: [AWS sts 200 0.432s 0 retries] getCallerIdentity({})
Serverless: [AWS cloudformation 200 0.49s 0 retries] describeStacks({ StackName: '***********-********-***' })
platform-sdk fetching: POST https://api.serverless.com/core/tenants/********/applications/******-*****-*******/services/***********-********/stages/dev/regions/**-****-*/deployments
Serverless: Successfully published your service to the Serverless Dashboard: https://dashboard.serverless.com/tenants/********/applications/******-*****-*******/services/***********-********/stage/dev/region/**-****-*
```

I see the:

```sh
  patchOperations: 
   [ { op: 'replace'
```

in those logs, maybe it's just trying to do an update operation and not trying to create the resource again because it thinks there're already there. I tried `sls deploy --force` but the same result.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue is caused by how Serverless handles, tracks, and deploys your functions and resources. When you deleted the API Gateway method you effectively changed the state of your application manually, and it is basically out of sync.

To resolve this, in your serverless.yaml file, comment out the entire method that you manually deleted, and run sls deploy. When its finished uncomment the method and sls deploy again. This time it should deploy your method again.

Comment: ⚠️ Be very careful with this solution as the API Gateway may get deleted the first time when you comment out the resource. 

Comment: In my experience the API Gateway might only be deleted if there are no other resources, otherwise only the method will be deleted, not the entire gateway.